Understanding No Arbitrage Assumption
I knew that If two portfolios have the same profit at maturity time T, then for all prior times $t<T$ the price of the portfolio's must be equal and this comes from no arbitrage assumption.
I am trying to understand the "price" we are referring here, is it an expected price?
For example, when I saw the proof for no early exercise for American call options by replicating a portfolio with a call option ($C_t$) with strike $K$ and zero-coupon bonds pays $K$ at maturity, by no arbitrage assumption, we later claim that
$$C_t + e^{-r(T-t)}K \geq S_t$$
Is this $S_t$ an expectation of the stock price?
The option prce $C_t$ is an expectation discounted and hence implying that the price of stock $S_t$ should also be a discounted expectation. Otherwise, it does not make sense to compare an expectation to a random variables right?
Another example I am thinking is simply having a portfolio that have the same price as stock at $T$ in Black-scholes world. It seems that the "price" of the portfolio and the stock is an expected price because the stock price $S_T$ is itself a random variable and it makes sense to referred to its expectation rather than any single realisation.

'I am trying to understand the "price" we are referring here, is it an expected price?' --> There is no such thing as expected price today. Today's price is today's price. And today's price is the expectation of future payout or equivalently by the tower property the expectation of future prices.

@TJT: That constraint that you wrote is true for every $t$ so there's no expectation needed. It's the actual price at time $t$.

@markleeds but isn't the price for example of european options in BS world at any time t
, an discounted expectation of its price/pay-off at time T
(maturity)

@markleeds Thanks for you reply! I am not referring to any specific books. As I have seen this "no arbitrage" statement being used in multiple places and in example I pointed out here - proving no early exercise for American call. The $C_t$ is an expectation discounted and hence implying that the price of stock $S_t$ should also be a discounted expectation. Otherwise it doesn't make sense. So the satement in this case is about some "expectation" right?

TJT: Forget my previous answer. I was zoning out and rushing. What you are referring to is the value of the call on the stock. So, don't confuse the value of the call with the stock price. I'll read your other comment later cause I gotta go TOTALLY forget what I said earlier regarding the S_t being the discounted payoff. That's WRONG and sorry for confusion. Will read other comment and reply correctly.  But I don't take back my comment regarding Cox and Rubenstein  A really nice book, particularly for what you are asking about.

TJT: I think you're trying to take that relation and connect it it to the VALUE of the call. The relation above just lets gets one closer to the actually value of the call by putting a bound on it using an arbitrage argument.  All that equation is saying the value of the call, $C_t$ is greater than the stock price minus the discounted strike price. This is because, if it wasn't, then the person could sell the call ( to someone ) buy the stock and pay off the call at expiration and still profit. That can't happen so that relation exists.

But, as far as the call being the expected discounted payoff etc, that material comes later when one is deriving the actual value of the call. This is where one discusses risk-neutrality etc so really a different topic. I think you might find cox and rubenstein interesting because they discuss arbitrage concepts without ever getting into risk-neutrality ( as far as I can remember ). But, as I said earlier in my deleted comment, I think you're ahead of yourself in terms of topics. It's just a relation that exists because otherwise, there's free money out there for the grabbing.

This relation  that you wrote probably came about in the 50's when everyone was trying to find the value of the call option using various techniques. I definitely know that it arose waaaaaay before Black and Scholes ( one could include Samuleson and Merton ) found the actual value of the call. This is 1973 so atleast the 50's . https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall09/cos323/papers/black_scholes73.pdf

@markleeds I am not sure I understand your argument completely. I think this no arbitrage assumption is closely related to risk neutral pricing as it is one of the key assumption. And when you mention about stock price, I find ambiguity in it. Because stock price is at any instance follows a distribution, It is a random variable. If you run simulation, there could be instances/realisation that have $S_t - e^{-(T-t)}K$ greater than the option price. More rigorously, through Jensen Inequality, no early exercise can be proved and in that, the it contains expectation of $S_t$

Hi TJT: the no arbitrage expression is just putting a bound of the value of the call. The differential equation of B&S does derive from an arbitrage argument but it's a totally different arbitrage argument from the one you wrote. So, IMHO, the arbitrage relation that you wrote down is distantly related to risk neutral pricing or the B&S differential equation.

Note that, although the $S_t$ is a random variable BEFORE time $t$, it's not a random variable at time $t$ if we assume that time $t$ is now. In that case, $S_t$ is known. So, all that relation is saying is that, for any time $t$, if one is at that time $t$, then the value of the call at time $t$ has to be greater than or equal to the price of the stock at time $t$ minus the discounted value of the strike K. So, there are no random variables in the expression because it's true for all times $t$ where t is the current time. Does that make more sense ?

The relation that you wrote down has to be atleast a good 10 years BEFORE the closed form solution derived by Black and Scholes. Some would say that risk neutral pricing is part of B&S (  but they kind of hand waved the replacement of $\mu$ by $r$) ? Others would say that it was 5-10 years after B&S ( Harrison and Pliska ).

TJT:  I don't know if anything is any clearer but I strongly suggest going through this slowly ( I should too ).  Actually, I recommend the full text but this is kind of a summary or atleast gives a good picture of what the text is like.
https://bpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/u.osu.edu/dist/7/36891/files/2017/07/CRR79-1yy8av8.pdf

TJT: I didn't explain the arbitrage ( implied by the expression ) correctly so I'll try to semi-fix it here. $C_t$ and the expression on the RHS, give the same payoff at expiration if $S_T > K$. So, one could argue that, since they give the same conditional payoff, their value must be the same. But, before payoff at expiration ( early exercise ), the thing on the RHS can be negative whereas the LHS can be at worst zero. Therefore, the value of the LHS has to be greater than the RHS for all $t$. Forget my earlier arbitrage argument and see C&R for full and better argument.

The statement is that if two investments have the same payoff , in all states of the world , at some future time T , then they have the same price today.  So there is no ‘expected price’ concept here.

but isn't the price for example of european options in BS world at any time $t$, an discounted expectation of its price/pay-off at time $T$ (maturity) ?

@TJT It's an expectation under the risk neutral measure (not the "real world" measure). I personally find it helpful to think of computing that expectation as a "trick" to find the value of a hedging portfolio.

For a stock, a price is a value we can see and know today. A price does not depend on a distribution.
To use your second example, and I'm going to rephrase a bit, there is a stock $S$, at times $0 \leq t \leq T$ we can observe its price which we call $S_t$. There is also some portfolio $X_t$ which has the property $X_T = S_T$. In a sense we don't even need to know the distribution of $S_T$ to know that $X_t = S_t$. The only thing we need to know about the distribution is that $P(S_T = X_T) = 1$ (hopefully you can convince yourself that there are many different distributions for $S_T$ and $X_T$,indeed with different expectations, that have this property)
The no arbitrage argument from there basically boils down to saying that if $X_t \neq S_t$, then you can buy the cheap one, sell the expensive one, and for every realization of $S_T$ then you're perfectly hedged by your opposing position in $X_T$, so you can pocket the (strictly positive) difference and take on no risk.
When you say the option price is an expectation, well, that's technically true, but it's a bit circular. I personally find it beneficial to think that the option price is the value of the portfolio that hedges the option, and that taking the "expectation" (which is under the risk-neutral measure -- not a measure designed to model "real world probabilities") is simply a trick to find that value.
